# JavaScript RegEx Elements Match

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match elements with a name that is `'container1$container2$chkChecked'`, using a regex of `'.+\$chkChecked'`, but I'm not getting the matches I expect when the element name is as described.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So what are you expecting and what are you getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

my guess, by your use of quotes, is you did something like

```
re = new RegExp('.+\$chkChecked');
```

which won't work because js takes advantage of the \ in its string interpretation as an escape so it never makes it into the regex interpreter

instead you want

```
re = new RegExp('.+\\$chkChecked');
```

Answer (score 3):

try

```
string.match( /[$]chkChecked$/ )
```

alternatively, you could try

```
string.match( /[^a-zA-Z0-9]chkChecked/ )
```

( Also, make sure your using `//` around your regex, otherwise you might be matching using string literals. Not obvious tho without a larger code snippet )

Answer (score 2):

There's two levels of escaping: one when your code is first parsed (e.g. in case you want to include a `'` inside the string), and the second in the regexp engine. So you need two `\s` before the `$` to make the regexp engine not treat it as a special character.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it should work.

There's a good [Javascript Regex Tester](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html) that also says it matches.

Answer (score 0):

> > Steven Noble:
>
> which won't work because js takes advantage of the \ in its string interpretation as an escape so it never makes it into the regex interpreter

I intended to use \ as an escape because I'm really looking for a $ in the element name.